# Python including existing variable when asking for input

Tags: python

I'm trying to have a loop that a user enters names for sectors of a graph. The idea was something like this(where number of sectors was assigned a value earlier through user input).

```
for z in range(0, numSectors):
     labels = input('Enter the label for sector',z,': ')
```

Is it not possible to have a variable like Z put in the argument or did I just not format it correctly somehow. If this is not possible in anyway, how would I go about achieving the same result in that case.

The question should read in the console like

```
Enter the label for sector 1:
Enter the label for sector 2:
Enter the label for sector 3:

...

(until the number of sectors is fulfilled)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format),

```
for z in range(1, numSectors+1):
    labels = input('Enter the label for sector {z}: '.format(z=z))

# Test result
Enter the label for sector 1: Hello
Enter the label for sector 2: World
Enter the label for sector 3: !
```

BTW, for Python2, use `raw_input` instead of `input`.